# why am i reciving No such content frame exception?

Tags: python, selenium, autologin, alfresco-webscripts

I am trying to auto fill the username and password text field to auto login in to my institution provided account

the python script is as followed

```
 from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def page_is_loaded(ion_driver):
    return ion_driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") != None

ion_driver = webdriver.Firefox()
ion_driver.get("https://muj.dvois.com")
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(ion_driver, 10)
wait.until(page_is_loaded(ion_driver))
input_field = ion_driver.find_element_by_name("username")
pass_field = ion_driver.find_element_by_name("password")
input_field.send_keys("j_169105214")
pass_field.send_keys('strawhat')
```

and the website is as

```
    <tr>                                    
<td><font align="right" class="newheaderfont">User Name</font></td>                                 <td><input name="username" type="text"></td>                                </tr>

    <tr>                                    
<td><font align="right" class="newheaderfont">Password</font></td>                                  <td><input name="password" type="password"></td>                                </tr>
```

and the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vidu/PycharmProjects/untitled/autologin_ion.py", line 10, in <module>
    ion_driver.get("https://muj.dvois.com")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 250, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 238, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: No such content frame; perhaps the listener was not registered?

Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vidu/PycharmProjects/untitled/autologin_ion.py", line 10, in <module>
    ion_driver.get("https://muj.dvois.com")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 250, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 238, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: No such content frame; perhaps the listener was not registered?
```

also i tried to do a facebook login it is working fine

Comment: Which line is the cause of exception? Also share `Firefox`, `selenium` versions

Comment: updated the full error